# Android Navigation Component: Hitting back results in NavController being out of sync

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm in the process of migrating an app from manual backstack manipulation via `FragmentManager` to using the new navigation library. The app consists of a `MainActivity` that has a `DrawerLayout` with 10-12 items in the drawer. When tapped some fragment manipulation happens and a new fragment is shown.

There's enough code in this production application that it's not feasible to simply rip out the old navigation structure and move to the navigation library whole cloth.

Instead, what I'm doing is migrating drawer item by drawer item. For example - There's a feature called check deposit which is accessed via an item in the nav drawer. When you tap that item, you're shown a new fragment and you can progress through a check deposit wizard-like flow. So far what I've done is created a new `RootCheckDeposit` fragment whose `View` consists of a single `FragmentContainerView` that houses a nav graph. Then the whole "flow" of that check deposit wizard is navigated through in the nav graph that's ultimately contained in the `RootcheckDeposit`.

Here's the layout for that `RootCheckDeposit` fragment:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/check_deposit_graph" />
```

That's working mostly ok, though the integration with the toolbar is still a bit wonky.

But the main problem I'm having is that as you progress through this wizard, hitting back can cause the `NavController` to get into a state where it seems to think it's on a different fragment than it actually is. This is reliably happening in the following flow within the check deposit wizard:

Loading screen -> Terms screen -> Check deposit landing screen.

Once you get to the check deposit landing screen, if you hit back nothing happens - which is fine. What's not fine is if you then click on a button in that landing screen that would progress you through the wizard the app crashes with an `IllegalArgumentException`, claiming that we're trying to use an action that's not available from `Loading Screen`. Which is weird because we're not on the `Loading Screen`, we're on the `Check Deposit Landing Screen`.

Here's my nav graph file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/check_deposit_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/loadingFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loadingFragment"
        android:name="module.checkdeposit.loading.TermsLoadingFragment"
        android:label="@string/check_deposit_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/terms_loading_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loadingFragment_to_termsAndConditionsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/termsAndConditionsFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loadingFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loadingFragment_to_depositOptionsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/depositLandingFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loadingFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/termsAndConditionsFragment"
        android:name="module.checkdeposit.terms.TermsAndConditionsFragment"
        android:label="@string/check_deposit_terms_and_conditions"
        tools:layout="@layout/terms_and_conditions_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_termsAndConditionsFragment_to_depositLandingFragment"
            app:destination="@id/depositLandingFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/termsAndConditionsFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/depositLandingFragment"
        android:name="module.checkdeposit.depositlanding.DepositLandingFragment"
        android:label="@string/check_deposit_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/deposit_landing_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_depositLandingFragment_to_depositHistoryFragment"
            app:destination="@id/depositHistoryFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_depositLandingFragment_to_scanCheckFragment"
            app:destination="@id/scanCheckFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/depositHistoryFragment"
        android:name="module.checkdeposit.deposithistory.DepositHistoryFragment"
        android:label="@string/check_deposit_deposit_history"
        tools:layout="@layout/deposit_history_fragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/scanCheckFragment"
        android:name="module.checkdeposit.scancheck.ScanCheckFragment"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/scan_check_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

Of note - when we go from `Loading screen` to `Terms screen` to `Landing Screen` we're popping each item because I don't want the user to be able to go "back" to a loading screen or a terms screen.

Things I've tried:

- Changing the `popUpTo` logic in the nav graph to point to the actual nav graph instead of the destination
- Check to see if the result of `navController.popBackStack` is `true` or `false` and take some action accordingly

I've also combed through the actual `NavController` code, and what seems to be happening is that the `NavController` is popping its internal backstack when back is clicked but not changing destinations because there's really no other destination to go to. It just seems like the `NavController` is then in a weird inconsistent state where it and the currently displayed `Fragment` are out of whack/not pointing to the same thing.

Has anyone else done this sort of migration with any success?

EDIT: I've created a repo that has a minimal project to recreate the crash I'm running into: https://github.com/alexsullivan114/ExampleNavigationCrashRepo. This repo kind of mimics the structure of the production app I'm working on. If you click into the slideshow drawer item then continue clicking on the text in the screens until you get to `Next Example Fragment` then hit back a few times and click the text again you'll see the crash.

I'm sure the issue is in how I've setup the navigation library, I'm just not sure what the right way is **without rewriting the rest of the apps navigation**

Comment: "if you hit back nothing happens - which is fine" - no, that's not fine and a signal that you're handling back incorrectly. Are you overriding `onBackPressed()` and manually calling `popBackStack()`? That should not be necessary if you've set up your Fragment hierarchy correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the error. I used your nav graph and lots of almost empty Fragments - everything works as it should (specifically pressing BACK from LandingFragment allows me to return to the Fragment before the CheckDepositRoot Fragment). If you need more help consider sharing a [MCVE] with the problem behavior

Comment: @ianhanniballake You're right - my sense was more "I'm ok with that behavior". I'm *very* open to the idea that I've setup my fragment hierarchy incorrectly, I'm just not sure what the correct way of setting it up is. In essence I don't really understand what _should_ happen when you hit "back" on the last fragment in the navigation stack. Should nothing happen? Should the whole graph be popped? It's unclear to me.

Comment: @BömachtBlau When you say "pressing BACK from LandingFragment allows me to return to the Fragment before the CheckDepositRootFragment", what's before the check deposit root fragment? In my app, that's root of that navigation stack, so there's nowhere really to "back" into unless you change nav drawer items (or exit the app).

I'll try and get a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, please do so. The MCVE frequently is a good idea. It's always possible that my setup accidentally fixes the error. Or  that I assume the wrong things like how the users get to CheckDepositRootFragment.

Comment: "so there's nowhere really to "back" into unless you change nav drawer items (or exit the app)" - then it sounds like you should be exiting your app. That's the default behavior when there is no Navigation stack left and why I asked if you override `onBackPressed()`, which you shouldn't need to do.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yeah that makes sense, exiting the app makes the most sense. That being said the real issue is the crash I'm running into. I've posted a sample project that kind of mimics the structure of my production app (albeit in a much more minimal version). I'm _sure_ that the issue is in how I've setup the navigation component, I'm just not sure what the right way is to set it up without migrating the entire apps navigation stack...

Comment: @BömachtBlau See the edit for a sample project. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @ianhanniballake I realized I never really answered your first question - I _am_ overring `onBackPressed` (or rather add a back pressed callback listener) and calling `popBackStack()`. If I don't do that, digging into a sub fragment then hitting back will exit the whole application, which isn't expected behavior. I feel like the fact that I'm using the navigation library entirely within one sort of "container" fragment is messing things up here. Is that not a supported flow?

Comment: So are you calling `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` on the parent fragment as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#considerations)? That's what automatically routes the back button to Navigation only when it has a back stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [considerations for child and sibling fragments guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#considerations):

> Only one FragmentManager is allowed to control the fragment back stack at any given time. If your app shows multiple sibling fragments on the screen at the same time, or if your app uses child fragments, then one FragmentManager must be designated to handle your app's primary navigation.
>
> To define the primary navigation fragment inside of a fragment transaction, call the [setPrimaryNavigationFragment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setPrimaryNavigationFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) method on the transaction, passing in the instance of the fragment whose childFragmentManager should have primary control.

As explained in the [Interact programmatically with Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#create_a_navhostfragment), the `app:defaultNavHost="true"` is calling `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` for you on the `NavHostFragment` itself, but you **aren't** calling `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` on the parent fragment - your `RootSlideshowFragment`. This means that **none** of the logic to automatically handle the back button correctly is being called - you've essentially broke the chain from the activity to the parent fragment to the `NavHostFragment`. This causes you to intercept the back button even when there's no back stack (Navigation doesn't actually remove the last fragment when you pop it as otherwise it would not be present when your activity's exit animation is running).

Therefore to fix this, you need to:

1. Remove your `OnBackPressedCallback` from `RootSlideshowFragment`. It is not needed.
2. When you swap between fragments in your `MainActivity`, call `setPrimaryNavigationFragment()` on the new Fragment:

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuitem ->
    val newFragment = when (menuitem.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_home -> HomeFragment()
        R.id.nav_gallery-> GalleryFragment()
        else -> RootSlideshowFragment()
    }
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, newFragment)
        .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(newFragment)
        .commit()
    true
}
```

Comment: As always @ianhanniballake your answer is extremely helpful. This fixed the issue - thank you!